# Question about ElGamal Encryption

Tags: encryption, elgamal-encryption

Is the encryption function of the ElGamal public-key cipher time-varying?

Comment: No, but it is [randomized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_encryption). ​ ​

Comment: Since we expect a significant amount of research before you ask here, please remember (for future questions) to add according information, which describes... What research have you done? What were your findings during research? What stopped you from finding the answer yourself?

Comment: By "time-varying", do you mean "taking a variable amount of time to compute" or "having a result that changes depending on the current time" (or something else)? The reason I ask is because @Ricky above and SEJPM below seem to have interpreted your question differently.

Answer (score 1):

As with everything, **it depends**.

The encryption function for ElGamal basically is $$(c_1,c_2)=(m\cdot\beta^k,\beta^k)$$ where $m$ is your message, $\beta$ is the recipient's public key and $k$ is chosen uniformly at random smaller than the order of the group.

Now the time taking for for the exponentiation and the multiplication depend heavily on your implementation. If it is crappy, the time may be a non-constant function of $k$, allowing an attacker to recover it and thus the message or the multiplication may be crappy and it depends on the values of the input, meaning you cold maybe deduce something about $m$ from the time.

If the implementation is properly done, it either always runs in constant time (relative to $m,k$) or it runs in completely random time, because the implementation is blinded, eg the implementation does something like $$(c_1,c_2)=((m^l\cdot\beta^{lk})^{l^{-1}},(\beta^{lk})^{l^{-1}})$$ (with $l$ chosen in the same way as $k$) for example.